# "Google Workspace services are managed by your administrator"

Tags: google-workspace

Going to https://workspace.google.com/dashboard > Logging in with my admin account > See msg "Google Workspace services are managed by your administrator", but I am the administrator

Clearing cookies cache/incognito did not help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is expected. I am a Super Admin of my organization and it is basically a default message that you can actually add a message below with a description, it would always give you that alert:

[image]

Just for reference of my account as Super Admin and the section where you can add the other message:

[image]

Comment: thank you, how do I access the admin dashboard from there?

Comment: You can do it by going to: https://admin.google.com or just by clicking over the waffle or menu at the top right corner, it should open the applications and show you one called "Admin".